# No actions available for my custom Drupal trigger

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am writing a Drupal module (filemaker) and defined some custom triggers. The triggers show up just fine, but say 'No available actions for this trigger.' at admin/build/trigger/filemaker.

Any idea how to make actions available for my trigger?

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_hook_info().
 */
function filemaker_hook_info() {
  return array(
    'filemaker' => array(
      'filemaker' => array(
        'create' => array(
          'runs when' => t('After creating a FileMaker record'),
        ),
        'update' => array(
          'runs when' => t('After updating a FileMaker record'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_filemaker().
 */
function filemaker_filemaker($op, $node) {
  $aids = _trigger_get_hook_aids('filemaker', $op);
  $context = array(
    'hook' => 'filemaker',
    'op' => $op,
    'node' => $node,
  );
  actions_do(array_keys($aids), $node, $context);
}

[...]
    // Fire off the hook.
    module_invoke_all('filemaker', 'create', $node);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Found the answer [here](http://drupal.org/node/375833).

Needed a hook_action_info_alter().

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info_alter().
 */
function filemaker_action_info_alter(&$info) {

  // Loop through each action.
  foreach ($info as $type => $data) {

    // Only add our trigger to node or system actions.
    if (stripos($type, "node_") === 0 || stripos($type, "system_") === 0) {

      // Don't remove any triggers that are already added to the approved list.
      if (isset($info[$type]['hooks']['application'])) {
        $info[$type]['hooks']['filemaker'] = array_merge($info[$type]['hooks']['filemaker'], array('create', 'update'));
      }

      // Add our trigger to the approved list of hooks.
      else {
        $info[$type]['hooks']['filemaker'] = array('create', 'update');
      }
    }
  }
}
```